# Using CustomMessageBox with WP8

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my WP8 app I have to use the CustomMessageBox. I use VB.NET and saw [here](http://shawnoster.com/2012/10/welcome-custommessagebox-to-the-windows-phone-toolkit/) I had to use the WP Toolkit which I added to my XAML like this :

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

The thing I want to do is simple, it isn't complicated with other controls in the message box, just modifying the buttons text.
Now my problem is simple : I just can't create my CustomMessageBox Object. On the link I gave, you can see the example is :

```
CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
```

with some parameters. It's C# but basically it should work with VB.NET this way :

```
Dim myMessageBox as CustomMessageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
```

But Visual Studio says "***the type `CustomMesageBox` is not defined***". Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already downloaded the the toolkit and added it as project reference, possibly you missed adding Imports (`using` in C#):

```
Imports Microsoft.Phone.Controls
```

Comment: No, it's not this because I've got these statements at the beginning of my code :

`Imports System.Net.Http

Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Imports System.IO.IsolatedStorage

Imports System.Windows.Controls

Imports Microsoft.Phone.Controls

Imports System.Windows

Imports System`

Comment: I tried creating new WP 8 project using VB, install WP toolkit from nuget, and `CustomMessageBox` is recognized... Try to use full name like `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.CustomMessageBox` does it work?

Comment: Or my assumption was wrong, you haven't added reference to Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact the package was not installed (but I don't understand why, I remember having installed it)